# Dojo instanceof returning true for parent class

Tags: class, dojo, radix

I have three classes Container, Stage and View. Stage inherits from Container, View also inherits from Container. When I call `instanceof` on an instance of the View class (View object), I get the following results

```
dojo.declare("View", [Container] , {
    constructor: function(){
        console.log(this.name + ' is a container-> ' + (this instanceof Container));
        console.log(this.name + ' is a View-> ' + (this instanceof View));
        console.log(this.name + ' is a Stage-> ' + (this instanceof Stage));
        this.preLoad();
    },
});
```

The output is

```
XYZ is a container -> true
XYZ is a View -> true
XYZ is a Stage -> false
```

How do I find the child class name/type?

[this](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/declare.html#isinstanceof) provides a work around for multiple inheritance, but it's not what i am looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a possible solution a bit further in the link you provided: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/declare.html#meta-information

Basically, any object created from a `declare`'d class has a `declaredClass` attribute, if you named the class. So you can do:

```
dojo.declare('ns.Foo', [], {});
dojo.declare('ns.Bar', [ns.Foo], {});

var x = new ns.Bar();
console.log(x.declaredClass == 'ns.Bar');  // true
```